# Как сохранить массив в базу данных SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать хранение массива в базе данных? Долго гуглил, но толком ничего не понял. Если можно, то объясните подробно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: для того, чтобы получить подробный ответ, нужно написать подробный вопрос. какой именно массив, например. тип, размерность  и тд

Comment: Например, итерировать массив и сохранять каждый элемент отдельной записью в БД.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим есть массив `int[] array`, который вы хотите положить в БД. Допустим, что порядок следования элементов важен. Тогда создаем табличку:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    _id             integer primary key autoincrement,
    myColumn        integer not null,
    orderColumn     integer
);
```

Далее складываем туда:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
for(int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("myColumn", myArray[i]);
    values.put("orderColumn", i);
    db.insert("myTable", null, values);
}
```

Для извлечения массива, применяем запрос:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("myTable", new String[]{"myColumn", "orderColumn"},
            null, null, null, null, "orderColumn asc");
int myArray = new int[cursor.getCount()]; //аллоцируем по количеству записей
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        myArray[i++] = cursor.getInt(0);
    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в базу данных вот такой массив private String[] team7array = {"один", "два", "три"}; ?  Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Дальше уже сами - я и так написал вам много :)